# iTunes Connect App Update release date clarification

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, updates

So in iTunes Connect I submitted an app update selecting the option to "automatically release" the update when approved. Now my issue is, will that option abide by the release date I set in the rights and pricing tab or no?

I have selected the date in the rights and pricing to the future and have deselected all countries also so when the app update is approved, it will not be live on the app store correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct. When the app is approved, it will not be visible in the app store immediately if the release date is set as a future date.

But when you set your release date to future, not just the update but the current version will also stop appearing in the app store. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Ok so just be certain, whatever is set in the app's rights and pricing will overrule that setting that I set when making the update, right?

Comment: Ok and another minor question, you cannot update keywords after the app is accepted even though it is removed from the store by developer correct?

Comment: Did you mean 'removed from the store by developer' by setting a future date? If so, you cannot update the keywords after the app is approved.

Comment: Kind of, I meant by just deselecting all the countries the app is available in so in that case, darn. :)

Comment: I changed the availabity date on an app just now, and got the following feedback: "You have selected an Available Date in the future. This will remove your currently live version from the App Store until the new date. Changing Available Date affects all versions of the application, both Ready For Sale and In Review"